# Dojo/Dijit ById Set Arguments

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, dojo

Good Morning!  I can't seem to find what the third argument of dijit's ById.Set() function is or how it functions. In the example below, the code I'm now tasked with maintaining is setting an element's value property to a value passed in on a form. The question is what is the significance of the false?

```
dijit.ById("array").set("value",form.originalArray.value, false);
```

Comment: Can you tell me where you got this from? According to the docs the `set()` function from `dijit/_WidgetBase` (the base of all widgets) only accepts two parameters, so any source/reference can be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third value is a boolean that says whether to fire a change event when you set this value.

```
dijit.set("value", "foo")
```

defaults to true and will cause any event handlers to fire. Or you can set it to false to prevent the event from happening. This is not easily found in the documentation for some reason.

Here is a fiddle demo

[jsfiddle.net/ST2s2/](http://jsfiddle.net/ST2s2/)